# UIButton Background Change on click

Tags: ios4

Can anyone tell me how to change UIButton background image?I have a CustomtableView which is holding 4 buttons.It's like a quiz app.I want to show if the ans is correct or not loading two background image.If correct a green image and if wrong a red image.

And when another question is loaded.Reset them.It should happen in the click.I am done with all the loading functionality and logical task of score counting.I just need to change the button background image.Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do that just calling

```
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"green.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

or alternatively

```
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"green.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Documentation reference: 
[setImage:forState:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/setImage%3aforState%3a)
[setBackgroundImage:forState:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/setBackgroundImage%3aforState%3a)

Comment: it's not working..the image is changing when my second data is loading..i need to change it in the current click effect and refresh it with normal image when new question comes.Do you understand me sir?

Comment: Actually no...why do you say it's not working? The background image does not change? 
To restore the normal image you should just call one of those methods passing the normal image...

Comment: let me tell you my detail condition.I am loading 4 option with 4 simple white background color(with a image).then whn i click for the ans it should change the color of the clicked button based on the right or wrong answer(Red/Green image).And when the second question loads the color should be normal.It's like a quiz app.